# How to write multiple iptables rules in chef?

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I was trying to write multiple iptables for blocking certain subnets and it turns out **that the very last iptables rule is only getting implemented**. This is what I've put in the recipe:

```
execute "block_ports" do
    command "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 1> --dport <port> -j DROP"
    command "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 2> --dport <port> -j DROP"
    command "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 3> --dport <port> -j DROP"
    command "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 4> --dport <port> -j DROP"
end
```

Can someone please tell me how to write multiple iptables rules so that all get executed in Chef recipe?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you had asked this question before and it was linked to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715354/chef-multi-line-command).

If you want to run multiple `iptables` commands from *one* Chef resource, you can use the [bash](https://docs.chef.io/resources/bash) resource.

Example:

```rb
bash 'block_ports' do
  code <<-EOH
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 1> --dport <port> -j DROP
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 2> --dport <port> -j DROP
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 3> --dport <port> -j DROP
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 4> --dport <port> -j DROP
  EOH
end
```

Comment: This is not idempotent as duplicate rules will be added if different Chef execution occurs

Answer (score 0):

The `execute` Chef resource allows only one **command** variable so if you write it multiple times only the latter one will be read. So you could just  call an execute *resource* for each rule to solve.

Anyway I suggest you to use the `iptables_rule` Chef resource of **iptables** cookbook. Check the documentation at https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/iptables for usages example.

Even if you can call the *iptables_rule* resource for each iptables rule I suggest instead to approach with a **source template** that contains all the rules you need in order to call it once.
So you can define your template file **rules.erb** file under `templates/default` directory on your cookbook as follow:

```
*nat
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <%= @subnet1 %> --dport <%= @dest_port %> j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <%= @subnet2 %> --dport <%= @dest_port %> j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <%= @subnet3 %> --dport <%= @dest_port %> j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <%= @subnet4 %> --dport <%= @dest_port %> j DROP
```

Then call once time the resource specifying templates variables as follow:

```
iptables_rule "rules.erb" do
          action [:disable, :enable] #If a rule already exists it isn't added again creating a duplicate
          variables(
             :port => d_port,
             :subnet1 => subnet_1,
             :subnet2 => subnet_2,
             :subnet3 => subnet_3,
             :subnet4 => subnet_4
          )
end
```

> Note that by default rebuild-iptables is "delayed" at the end of the whole Chef process. If you need to activate rules immediately once them have been added you can do it notifying, with *:immediate* attribute set, an **execute** resource that call manually call the rebuild-iptables command